# Uploadify for apk file doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, yii

Im currently using uploadify to upload file. I have upload apk file and upload png file for user to upload. Both im using same way... but why it only work in the png upload ... for apk file upload it did not copy the file to the folder. So I asking for help

PHP CODE:

```
<div class="div_upload_file_container">
<div style="position:absolute; margin: 0; padding:0; height:27px">              
        <input required="required" style="display:none" id="btnUploadFile" name="btnUploadFile" type="file" />                             
    </div>    
    <div class="div_upload_file_container_inner">                                      
    <div class='word'>

    </div>                         
        <div style='clear:both'></div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

JS FILE:

```
//file
        $('#btnUploadFile').uploadify({
        'swf': base_url + '/js/plugins/uploadify321/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader': "index.php?r=apk/uploadfile",   
        'queueID': 'uploaded_file',
        'progressData': 'speed',
        'removeCompleted': false,
        'width': $('.div_upload_file_container').width(),
        'height': 28,
        'fileTypeDesc': 'Image Files (*.apk)',
        'fileTypeExts': '*.apk',
        'fileSizeLimit': '100MB',
        'itemTemplate': uploadedFileItem(),
        'buttonText' : UPLOAD_FILE,
        'onSelect': function (file) {

        },
        'onUploadStart': function (file) {


        },
        'onUploadSuccess': function (file, data, response) {

            console.log (data)
            $('#' + file.id).html(file.name);

            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            statusCode = obj.statusCode;

            if (statusCode == '200'){

                var today = obj.today;
                var tmp_folder_with_date = obj.tmp_folder_with_date;
                var filesize = obj.filesize;
                var hashfilename_filename = obj.hashfilename_filename;
                var full_path = obj.full_path;              

                file_cnt ++;

                var html = '';
                html = '<div>';
                html += '<div style="float:left">';
                html += file_cnt + '.';
                html += '</div>';
                html += '<div style="float:left; margin: 0 0 0 10px">';
                html += file.name;
                html += '</div>';
                html += '<div style="clear:both"></div>';
                html += '</div>';

                $('#' + file.id).html(html);

            }

            var params = {
                fileid: file.id,
                fileName: obj.fileName,
                fullSavePath_original: obj.fullSavePath_original,
                fullSavePath_resize: obj.fullSavePath_resize,
                fullSavePath_tobesave: obj.fullSavePath_tobesave,
                fullSavePath_tobesaveURL: obj.fullSavePath_tobesaveURL,
                filesize: obj.fileSize,
                fullPath_TempFolder: obj.fullPath_TempFolder,
                orientation: obj.orientation,
                tobesave_file_width: obj.tobesave_file_width,
                tobesave_file_height: obj.tobesave_file_height,
                todayTempFolder: obj.todayTempFolder
            };

            DisplayNewUploadedPhotos(params);

        },
        'onUploadComplete': function (file) {

        },
        'onCancel': function (file) {

        },
        'onDialogClose': function (queueData) {

        },
        'onInit': function (instance) {

        },
        'onQueueComplete': function (queueData) {

        },
        'onClearQueue': function (queueItemCount) {

        }
    });

    function uploadedFileItem() {

        var html = '';      

        html = '<div id="${fileID}" class="fileUploadedItem">';     
        html += '<div style="margin:10px 0 0 0"></div>';
        html += '<div class="uploadify-progress-bar"></div>';
        html += '<div style="margin:10px 0 0 0">';
        html += '<center><a href="#">Cancel</a></center>';
        html += '</div>';
        html += '</div>';

        return html;
    }
```

CONTROLLER:

```
public function actionUploadFile()
{               

    if (isset($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'])) {                      

        $today = date("Ymd");     

        $slash = Yii::app()->params['slash'];   
        $tmp_folder = Yii::app()->params['tmp_folder'];
        $tmp_folder_with_index_file = $tmp_folder . $slash . 'index.html';
        $tmp_folder_with_date = Yii::app()->params['tmp_folder'] . $today;      

        if (!is_dir($tmp_folder_with_date)){
            mkdir($tmp_folder_with_date, 0755);                     
            copy($tmp_folder_with_index_file, $tmp_folder_with_date . $slash . 'index.html');
        }                   

        $filesize = sprintf("%u", filesize( $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'] )); 

        $hashfilename_filename = md5(time() + 1) . '.apk';  

        $full_path = $tmp_folder_with_date . $slash . $hashfilename_filename;

        if (!move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], $full_path)){             
            $result['statusCode'] = "500";  
            echo json_encode($result);      
            die();
        }                       

        $result['statusCode'] = "200";          
        $result['today'] = $today;  
        $result['tmp_folder_with_date'] = $tmp_folder_with_date;        
        $result['filesize'] = $filesize;    
        $result['hashfilename_filename'] = $hashfilename_filename;  
        $result['full_path'] = $full_path;      

    }else{
        $result['statusCode'] = "400";          
    }       

    echo json_encode($result);      
    die();
}
```

Comment: What is the file size of the PNG file? And the APK file?

Comment: @SetSailMedia Hi, thanks for comment ...  set the png filesize for '100*100' and apk i set '100MB'

Comment: @SetSailMedia any idea ?

Comment: I mean the actual files you are trying to upload from your disk, what size are they? Probably it is too large and you need to adjust some settings in php.ini  to allow large file uploads. This is a very common problem that people encounter.

Comment: @SetSailMedia did u know the "some settings" is which setting ?

Comment: these are the configuration settings to verify: upload_max_filesize, post_max_size, memory_limit, max_execution_time, max_input_time

Comment: i set upload_max_filesize=100%, post_max_size=100%, memory_limit=100%, max_execution_time=30, max_input_time=60 ... but still cant ... any suggestion ?

Comment: @SetSailMedia i set upload_max_filesize=100%, post_max_size=100%, memory_limit=100%, max_execution_time=30, max_input_time=60 ... but still cant ... any suggestion ?

Comment: @SetSailMedia I try txt and png it work fine can copy to the targer folder... i also have try upload 4mb apk file but it still doesn't work ...

Comment: @SetSailMedia i fixed it =D thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Go xampp->php->php.ini search "post_max_size" and make it post_max_size=100M

Problem solved =D